# How to preview mobile site in <iframe> in desktop version of site in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I want to show mobile version of website in desktop version .
Basically we have 2 website m.xyz.com and xyz.com , now what i want is to show m.xyz.com in desktop on click of preview .

```
<script>
$('#preview_feature').click(function() {

            $('.faqModal').on('shown.bs.modal',function(){     

              $(this).find('iframe').attr('src','https://m.xyz.com/abc')
            })
              $('.faqModal').modal({show:true})
            })
    </script>

    //On click of this button i am showing model which will preview mobile version of website 
    <button type="button" id="preview_feature" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn"  >Preview Feature</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade faqModal" id="faqModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Preview</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <iframe style="width:940px;height:560px;-webkit-transform:scale(1);-moz-transform-scale(1);"></iframe>
              </iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Does your mobile website support a width of 940px?

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal basically problem is because i am trying to preview mobile site page in website . So if i will remove width or i will give some other width i doesn't matter. By any chance is it possible to load mobile site in desktop ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to load mobile site in desktop if you fix the width of your iframe to somewhat equal to the mobile resolution it can show the mobile website. @SumitNair

Comment: I tried doing same still it is redirecting to www.abc.com . Can we change user-agent of iframe ? So that it will open m.abc.com @AniruddhAgarwal

Comment: you can set using js in abc.com that if the window size is less than like 500px or something it should redirect to m.abc.com

Comment: Can you provide the site link so, that I can check on my end? what could be possible.

Comment: The problem is with redirection it doesn't allow any user from desktop to access mobile site . I just want to preview mobile site not able to do so

Comment: you can try with https://m.youtube.com also it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

See this is working for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" width="400px" height="500px">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please try decreasing the width so that if it using proper js for mobile platform redirection then it will be working fine.

Comment: Sure i will try and let you know

Comment: @SumitNair I will wait for your feedback to work more on this.

Comment: Still not working i think i should try changing USERAGENT @aniruddh Agarwal

Comment: the m.abc.com is also yours?

Comment: I am asking are you the owner of that website which you are trying to access in iframe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165200/discussion-between-aniruddh-agarwal-and-sumit-nair).